# Curl Inside While loop results in fails due to syntax error

Tags: unix, curl, while-loop

I am trying to call variable inside while loop curl. If the pass the value directly it works fine but if I pass as variable it keeps failing.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]];
do
   curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:8080/_count?pretty' -d '
   {
      "query": {
      "bool": {
      "must": [ {
             "term": {
                      "M": "image"
                     }
                }, {
             "term": {
             "C": "$line"
           }}]}}}'
  done < "$1"
```

say my sample file is having the data :--

```
 ABC:124:456
 ABC:345:786
```

I am not sure why it running into syntax error . Anywhere I am missing anything?

Regards

Comment: Shell variables aren't expanded inside single quotes.

Comment: Is there any hack around it ?

Answer (score 0):

@John Gordon .. Thank you . I was able to fix it with your inputs.

"Shell variables aren't expanded inside single quotes"

Answer (score 0):

You could use double quotes to enable shell variable expansion and quote the double quotes that you want to pass to curl.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]];
do
   curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:8080/_count?pretty' -d "
   {
      \"query\": {
      \"bool\": {
      \"must\": [ {
             \"term\": {
                      \"M\": \"image\"
                     }
                }, {
             \"term\": {
             \"C\": \"$line\"
           }}]}}}"
  done < "$1"
```